# Complex Python object to JSON Conversion

Tags: python, json, class, oop

I need to convert a complex python object to JSON, by complex I mean an object that contains int variables, string variables, and 2 lists of custom objects.

My Python object's constructor is:

```
 def __init__(self, skills="",vid=""):
    self.Skills = list([])
    for skillID in skills.split("-"):
        if not skillID == "":
            tmpSkill = Skill()
            tmpSkillObj = DBCommands.getSkill(skillID)
            tmpSkill.ID = tmpSkillObj[0][0] #tmpSkillObj[0][0]
            tmpSkill.Name = tmpSkillObj[0][1]
            tmpSkill.isMain = True
            tmpSkill.CurrentlyTesting = False
            tmpSkill.isSub = False
            tmpSkill.Level = 0
            tmpSkill.Tested = False
            tmpSkill.Score = 0
            tmpSkill.Confidence = 0
            tmpSkill.BestScore = 0
            tmpSkill.ParentID = 0
            self.Skills.append(tmpSkill)
            self.AskedQuestions.append(tmpSkill)
    self.Skills = list(self.Skills)
    if not skills  == "":
        self.Skills[0].CurrentlyTesting = True #Start testing the first skill
    if not vid  == "":
        self.VacancyID = int(vid)
    self.PlayerID = 0
    self.Score = float(0)
    self.AskedQuestions = list([])
    self.MaxLevel = 0
    self.AssessmentIsFinished = False
```

I need a mechanism to encode the object and decode it.

Comment: Does it have to be json? Why not [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it instead?

Comment: The scenario is:
The server should convert the object to String(JSON), then encrypt this string and send it as a Token. 
When the server receive the token, It should be able to do the opposite work, decrypte the token, parse the string(JSON) to a new object.

Comment: that should work just fine with `pickle.dumps()`. Your object will be serialized and returned as a string which you can encrypt and transmit using whatever means you like

Comment: Especially if you intend to rebuild an identical object from this file you're sending securely, I would recommend `pickle` for its ease of re-building the object instance. With a .json, you'd have to create a special unpacking script that creates a new instance (basically an alternate `__init__` that reads json instead of normal inputs)

Comment: @Rawing and Aaron thank you guys, problem solved. I just used the pickle class and then encode it with base64 then decode it and load it into object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode:

```
import base64
import pickle
token = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(token,-1))
```

Decode:

```
import pickle
import base64
Obj = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(token))
```